# eclipse compile with different project types

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I am just starting to use both eclipse(neon) integrated with github and it was successful.
I have tested sample programs both as C Project - Executable and C Project - Shared Library.
But I don't understand how I can use them both in the same project as below.

I have whole project which may consist of ten binaries, and a couple of shared libraries which will be used by the binaries.
So my project structure will be

/bin        (where binaries will be put)

/src        (which holds the source for binaries).

/libsrc     (which holds the source for shared libraies)

/include    (include files required by /src and /libsrc ).

/lib        (where shared objects will be kept).

I hope the my query is not confusing. How can I use multiple compiling types in a same project.

Comment: Your query is not confusing as there is no query.

Comment: Hi this is my query - 'But I don't understand how I can use them both in the same project as below.' Do you want me to explain more ?

Comment: Personally I avoid eclipse's managed build options and build everything using a `Makefile` so I have total control over everything. Also if you use the managed build options you don't get to know the build process as easily or learn the basics about how the compiler works. Also you can't easily migrate your project to other `IDE`s.

Comment: That is how I have compiled till date, write makefile on my own.. 
But eclipse gui looked cool and i thought i'll give a try. Is my query clear. Do you think the option exist ?

Comment: Looking at the available options it may be that you need to make several projects and link them together using the "Project References" option.

Comment: that is how i thought. Create 10 different executable projects and one project for shared libraries. 'Project References', I am hearing for the first time. Let me check it out

Comment: @libadarsh.so.1.0.1 Also you can create a `Working Set` that allows you to work with a selected group of projects.

Comment: Look into "build configurations" and "make targets"

Comment: @user4581301 In which case ? Eclipse makefile project or when using custom makefile ?

Comment: Select the project needing reference to the lib. Bring up the "Project properties" (Alt+Enter or right click on project and pick "Properties" from the popup menu). On the list on left, pick "Project references"

Comment: I think I have to check more on project references. thanks.